# Split a feed of Feedburner into multiple feeds by label

Tags: rss, blogger, feed, atom-feed, feedburner

How can I separate my feed of FeedBurner into multiple feeds?

My one is posted to FeedBurner from blogger.com and has category tag, which is label in Blogger. I tried to split items by label with Yahoo Pipe but couldn't make it because its filter only work with words in title and description.

[Here's the raw rss of my feed](http://engineerflies.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss)

[Blogger Feed URLs](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=97933)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up multiple feeds for the same blog based on label categories, use this format as [explained here](http://labnol.blogspot.in/2007/08/offer-rss-feeds-for-blogger-search.html) -

http://{yourblogname}.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/{label}

This trick still works for the reincarnated form of Feedburner.